# Is there a way generate a shortcut file with adobe air?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, filesystems, adobe

Good afternoon,
I would like create a application that can can create folders and short cuts to folders in the file system. The user will click a button and it will put a folder on there desktop that has short cuts to files like //server/folder1/folder2 Can you create a desktop shortcut with code in adobe air? How would you do that? How do you create a folder? I keep thinking this should be easy but i keep missing it. 
Thank you for your help sorry for the trouble,
Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your deployment profile is [Extended Desktop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html), you may be able to use [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) and some simple scripts that you could package with your app.  This approach would entail handling the functionality on a per OS basis, which would take some work and extensive testing.  However, I wanted to at least share a scenario that I verified does work.  Below is a test case that I threw together:

#### Test Case: Windows 7

Even though the [Adobe documentation says that it prevents execution of .bat files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html#WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-368e74cb123de962251-7ffd), apparently it doesn't prevent one from executing the Windows Scripting Host: *wscript.exe*.  This means you can execute any JScript or VBScript files.  And this is what you would use to write a command to create a shortcut in Windows (since Windows doesn't have a commandline command to create shortcuts otherwise).

Here's a simple script to create a shortcut command, which I found on [giannistsakiris.com](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/12/03/how-to-create-shortcuts-in-windows-from-the-command-line/), (converted to JScript):

```
// File: mkshortcut.js

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments.Named("shortcut") + ".lnk");
oShellLink.TargetPath = WScript.Arguments.Named("target");
oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1;
oShellLink.Save();
```

If you package this in your application in a folder named **utils**, you could write a function to create a shortcut like so:

```
public function createShortcut(target:File, shortcut:File):void {
  if (NativeProcess.isSupported) { // Note: this is only true under extendedDesktop profile
    var shortcutInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

    // Location of the Windows Scripting Host executable
    shortcutInfo.executable = new File("C:/Windows/System32/wscript.exe");

    // Argument 1: script to execute
    shortcutInfo.arguments.push( File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("utils/mkshortcut.js").nativePath);

    // Argument 2: target
    shortcutInfo.arguments.push("/target:" + target.nativePath);

    // Argument 3: shortcut
    shortcutInfo.arguments.push("/shortcut:" + shortcut.nativePath);

    var mkShortcutProcess = new NativeProcess();
    mkShortcutProcess.start(shortcutInfo);

  }
}
```

If one wanted to create a shortcut to the Application Storage Directory on the Desktop, the following would suffice:

```
var targetLocation:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
var shortcutLocation:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("Shortcut to My AIR App Storage");

createShortcut(targetLocation, shortcutLocation);
```

---

Obviously there's a lot of work to be done to handle different OS environments, but this is at least a step.

Comment: Your overview was the reason why I posted the second link

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns - Yeah, I looked at it before I posted my answer.  Honestly, the material in there is outdated (posted in 2008; targeting AIR 1.0) and really only has value if one were interested in a conceptual history of NativeProcess (introduced in AIR 2.0; now 3.1 is released).  Nevertheless, I did +1 your answer since you are correct that the File class lacks the ability to create shortcuts, and the _concept_ demonstrated in the CommandProxy example was in the right direction.

Comment: This is really good! I will have to give it a try but it looks like what i was looking for. Thanks for you help! It's really good to know that you can do the JScript because there could be other things that are possible. With the release of Flash Builder 4.6 i wander how hard it would be to make it into a native extension?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, File class does not allow the creation of symbolic links. But you can create directories with `createDirectory()`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#createDirectory%28%29

Check if this can be useful: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/

Answer (score 0):

Air doesnt let you create shortcuts natively. Here's a workaround that works with Windows [may work on Mac but I don't have a machine to test].

Using Air, create a file that contains the following plain text

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=C:\path-to-folder-or-file
```

Replace `path-to-folder-or-file` with your folder/file name

Save the file as `test.url`

Windows recognizes this file as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to coerce Adobe Air into creating symbolic links, other useful things, on a Mac. Here's how I did it:

You will need AIRAliases.js - Revision: 2.5

In the application.xml add:

```
<!-- Enables NativeProcess -->
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>
```

In the Air app JavaScript:

```
//    A familiar console logger 
var console = {
    'log' : function(msg){air.Introspector.Console.log(msg)}
};

if (air.NativeProcess.isSupported) {
    var cmdFile = air.File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("/bin/ln");

    if (cmdFile.exists) {
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo = new air.NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var processArgs = new air.Vector["<String>"]();

        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = cmdFile;
        processArgs.push("-s");
        processArgs.push("< source file path >");
        processArgs.push("< link file path >");
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
        nativeProcess = new air.NativeProcess();
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(air.NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onProcessExit);
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onProcessOutput);
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onProcessError);
        nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    } else {
        console.log("Can't find cmdFile");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Not Supported");
}

function onProcessExit(event) {
    var result = event.exitCode;
    console.log("Exit Code: "+result);
};

function onProcessOutput() {
    console.log("Output: "+nativeProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
};

function onProcessError() {
    console.log("Error: "+nativeProcess.standardError.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardError.bytesAvailable));
};
```

Altering the syntax of the command and parameters passed to NativeProcess you should be able to get real shortcuts on Windows too.